# Asking for confirmation when someone wants to change an upvote

Tags: sentence, expression-choice, internet

I am building a user facing software. I want to ask for the user's confirmation if they really want to change their vote.

For example:

A user once upvoted a post and then he wants to downvote it. Should I just say:

> Are you sure you want to change your vote?

or can I say:

> You upvoted it before. Are you sure you want to downvote it?

Which of the two is better?

Comment: You might get a better answer at [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: There is no such thing as “a software”, because *software* is a mass noun and therefore is not countable. Perhaps you meant “a program”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for the more universal **"Are you sure you want to change your vote?"** This sounds fine and is more concise.

It also has the added benefit of requiring less maintenance (when translating the software, for example), because the same message works for both upvotes and downvotes, while still being clear.